# Отправить форму с сайта на почту asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

На сайте есть форма обратной связи такого вида

[image]

нужно собирать данные из полей, сформировать из них письмо и оправлять на почту.

Я создаю для своей формы модель FeedbackForm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ComponentTrading.Web.Models
{
    public class FeedbackForm
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Email { get; set; } 
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Создаю представление Contacts.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contacts", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contact-form" }))
{
<fieldset>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @Value = Name })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @Value = "E-mail" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @Value = Phone })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow" })
    <input class="form-button" data-type="reset" value="Clear" />
    <input class="form-button" data-type="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</fieldset>     
}
```

И потом в моем HomeController пишу

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contacts()
    {
    FeedbackForm temp = new FeedbackForm();
    temp.Message = Message;
    return View(temp);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contacts(FeedbackForm Model)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("test@mail.ru", "Письмо с сайта");
    string body = "Name: " + Model.Name + "\n"
                + "Email: " + Model.Email + "\n"
                + "Phone: " + Model.Phone + "\n\n"
                + Model.Message;
    msg.Body = body;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);

    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.EnableSsl = false;

    try
    {
        client.Send(msg);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    FeedbackForm tempForm = new FeedbackForm();
    tempForm.Message = Message;
    return View(tempForm);
}
```

Не могу понять,
1. Где мне задать email, на который мне нужно оправлять письмо?
2. Сайт пока лежит на локальной машине. Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно установить у себя почтовый сервер, чтобы хотя бы потестить отправку писем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) В поле [To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to.aspx);

```
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("Jane@contoso.com");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = "Using the SmtpClient class.";
        message.Body = @"Using this feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
```

2) Да, нужен почтовый сервер.

Comment: что-то не открывается у меня ссылка. вот так нужно задать адрес отправки? `msg.To.Add("tayna-anita@mail.ru");`

Comment: 1) да, вот пример из MSDN:
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("Jane@contoso.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Using the SmtpClient class.";
message.Body = @"Using this feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";

2) тут определенно посоветовать не смогу, может быть hMailServer вам подойдет http://www.hmailserver.com/

Comment: про сервер не могу разобраться, получается, мне нужно будет установить почтовый сервер у себя локально, а потом, когда проект будут переносить на рабочую машину, там снова придется устанавливать и настраивать почтовый сервер? а если использовать что-то вроде MvcMailer https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide, то не получится обойтись без сервера?

Comment: у себя можете написать какой нибудь эмулятор почтового сервера. заглушку. для тестирования ведь не обязательно емейлы слать, достаточно например сообщения просто на локальный диск сохранять.

Comment: а как можно сделать сохранение сообщений на диск? что мне нужно поменять в моем коде? я с mvc совсем недавно работаю, мне пока сложно разобраться.

Comment: гугление по запросу "c# mailmessage save to file" и вот результат:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file

Comment: да, на диск сохранить получилось. если у меня при этом получается. что все тело письма в одну строчку `Name: Test Test=0AEmail: test@gmail.com=0APhone: 89208713260=0A=0A=
test test test test test test test test test test test test test =
test test test test test test test` то мне и на email будет в таком же виде приходить?